# C# element in byte array fails to be initialize, null byte fails to initialize

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
byte checksum;
byte[] toBuff = new byte[20];
toBuff = BitConverter.GetBytes(intNumBuffer);      
Array.Reverse(mybyte);
checksum = ComputeChecksum(toBuff); //int to byte array

// At this point, the array is something like this
//  toBuff[0] = 25
//  toBuff[1] = 0
//  toBuff[2] = 0
//  toBuff[3] = 0

toBuff[4] = checksum; //HERE IS WHERE OUR OF BOUNDS OCCURS
```

I am new and would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
toBuff = BitConverter.GetBytes(intNumBuffer);
```

The call to `BitConverter.GetBytes()` returns a byte array of length 4, because `intNumBuffer` is an `int`, which has size 4.

So, that means that the valid indices of `toBuff` are 0, 1, 2 and 3.  Hence the error when you use index 4.

Now, I suppose that you imagined that when you wrote:

```
byte[] toBuff = new byte[20];
```

that `toBuff` would have length 20. Well, it does at this point. But when you subsequently overwrite `toBuff`, then you have a new and different array.

Probably what you need to do is as follows:

```
byte[] toBuff = new byte[20];
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(intNumBuffer), toBuff, sizeof(int));
```

Or perhaps:

```
byte[] toBuff = new byte[20];
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intNumBuffer);
Array.Copy(intBytes, toBuff, intBytes.Length);
```

Either of these will copy the bits returned by the call to `GetBytes()` into `toBuff`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i just have one question, does that mean my array size changed, and memory of that array was changed to 4 bytes instead of 20, did the other 16 bytes return to free memory.

Comment: No, you created a new array. `toBuff` is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, because you only add an item in the range of 0 to 3.
You could check first if the toBuff[someIndex] actually has a value and thus is not null.

Answer (score 0):

BitCOnverter.GetBytes return an array of 4 check :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    toBuff = BitConverter.GetBytes(intNumBuffer);
```